# Shared enum between multiple threads

Tags: c#, enumeration, volatile, atomic, interlocked

I have an enumeration that is shared between multiple threads:

```
public enum Action
{
   Read,
   Write,
   None
}
```

Within a class I have a variable of Action type:

```
public Action _action;
```

This is a shared variable, that is, it is updated and read from multiple threads.

For example, from one thread I do:

```
_action = Action.Read
```

And from another one:

```
if (_action == Action.Read)
{
}
else if (_action == Action.Write)
{
}
else if (_Action == Action.None)
{
}
else
{
}
```

So I would like to use Interlock to update and/or read it from different threads at the same time. How can I do it through a property?

I have seen many posts, for example below one:

[How to apply InterLocked.Exchange for Enum Types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177169/how-to-apply-interlocked-exchange-for-enum-types-in-c)

Problem here is that enumeration needs to cast to an int, but I would like to keep enumeration without casting. Is it possible? If so, could you post some example? Also Is it possible to combine volatile with interlock? I mean apply interlock on a volatile enumeration.

Comment: This and the linked question are asking the same thing: "I know how to solve this problem with casting.  Can I solve it without casting?"  I don't think saying "No, really, I don't want to use casting" invalidates those answers or makes this not a duplicate.  You might try adapting some of the answers to the close-to-if-not-exactly-a-duplicate question [Interlocked.CompareExchange with enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18358518/150605), but I think you'll find that those solutions are no prettier/cleaner/more desirable than casting.  Really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario `Interlocked` wouldn't be useful. Your series of `if/then` checks depend on the value of `_action` remaining unchanged as they all execute. Otherwise `_action==Action.Read` could be false, but before the next statement executes `_action` is set to `Action.Read` and all of the other conditions are false.

You'd want to use `lock` to ensure that nothing modifies `_action` while those statements are executing.

So you might have an object for your lock:

```
private readonly _lockObject = new object();
```

And then when _action is getting set:

```
lock(_lockObject)
{
    _action = newValue;
}
```

And when executing your conditions you could just read the value of `_action` within the `lock` and then release it. That way the lock is held for the shortest time possible. If `_action` gets modified while you're executing your conditions you won't be affected because you've created a separate value and you're no longer depending on the value of  `_action`.

```
Action action;
lock(_lockObject)
{
    action = _action
}
if (action == Action.Read)
{
}
else if (action == Action.Write)
{
}
else if (action == Action.None)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: And it is a good idea to make variable _action volatile as well in combination with lock? for example public volatile Action _action