# Using switch case with thread safe enum

Tags: c#, switch-statement, thread-safety

If I have an `Enum` as follows:

```
private object myEnumValLock = new object();
private MyEnum _myEnumVal;
public MyEnum MyEnumVal
{
    get
    {
        lock(this.myEnumValLock)
        {
            return this._myEnumVal;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        lock(this.myEnumValLock)
        {
            if (value != this._myEnumVal)
            {
                this.HandleNewMyEnumVal(this._myEnumVal, value);
                this._myEnumVal = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When using switch case, can I directly use the property like this:

```
private void MyFunc()
{
    switch (this.MyEnumVal)
    {
        case MyEnum.First:
            // Do Something
            break;
        case MyEnum.Second:
            // Do Something
            break;
    }
}
```

Or should I read it first and then use switch on the read value like this:

```
private void MyFunc()
{
    var myEnumVal = this.MyEnumVal;
    switch (myEnumVal)
    {
        case MyEnum.First:
            // Do Something
            break;
        case MyEnum.Second:
            // Do Something
            break;
    }
}
```

If using `if ... else` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123466/shared-enum-between-multiple-threads), I'd need to read the value first. Is it the same case with `switch` statement? What is the behaviour of the `switch` statement? Does it read the value at every `case` statement or reads only once at the beginning?

Comment: I would directly use the property. (Unless of course i needed its value somewhere else in my function too and its path and name where really long)

Comment: @mjwills running on Windows 7/10 - x64/x86. As pointed out in the linked question, for `if ... else` it is necessary to read first. what is the behaviour of the `switch` statement? does it read the value at every `case` statement or reads only once at the beginning?

Comment: @mjwills How do you say so? In the equivalent `if .. else` example, it is shown that `c` is compared in every single case.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your getter. How many times does it get hit? What does that tell you?

Comment: It's a relatively large piece of code until I get there. Nevertheless, I'm on it.

Comment: @mjwills You're right. It gets hit only once. So I don't need to read it previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) suggested, I put a breakpoint in the getter and it got hit only once at the beginning of the `switch` statement. I can't find any specific reference where it says the `switch` statement reads the value only once (please comment if you find the reference). But the breakpoint does prove it.

So, although you need to have read the value beforehand in case of `if ... else`, in case of the `switch` statement, you don't need to.